# initialize size of the linked list in java

Tags: java

[image]

the error is ***The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable***

how can I solve this problem

Comment: What did you find in your exhaustive search of this issue on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on Google?

Comment: You just can't do this - you can *never* assign a value to the result of a method call. In this case, you should be looking for `setSize()` - but there's no such thing in `LinkedList`. It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve, but you should probably just add half the entries from `LL` to `left`. As an aside, please post code in questions *as text* rather than as screenshots.

Comment: Never ever post a screen shot. Please always post your code as TEXT. 25 points in your account, and I see its too late to tell you this.

Answer (score 2):

The `.size()` method only retrieves the number of elements in the list, you cannot assign a value to it.
Instead, do `size1 = left.size()`

Comment: "please don't post screenshots of code instead of writing it." should be a comment instead of part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error message here is clear. `left.size()` is a method call which returns a value. You cannot assign a value to a method call. You can only assign a value to a variable. If `size` were a variable instead of a method, this code might work. But more to the point, it's illogical to attempt to assign a size to a linked list. The size of a linked list grows as you add elements to it.